# Apache Beam "mvn package" fail, while works via Eclipse

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When using Eclipse IDE and related plugins, I am able to easily execute jobs both locally and on Dataflow - from the IDE.

When trying to "productize" the job (and due to a known Dataflow/Bigquery limitation I can't use templates), I am trying to use "mvn package" from command line in the "cloud build" environment - but it always fail with errors such as "package org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options does not exist".

My old code was Dataflow (SDK 1.9.0) and "mvn package" worked like charm.
Now, with Beam (SDK 2.1.0) I can't make it work.

Clearly, Eclipse "knows what it is doing", and all I need is to find what mvn flags are being in use via the IDE, and use them from the command line - but I fail to find it anywhere.

Any recommendations ?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by properly adding the missing `maven-jar-plugin`...